# why is the variable 'x' not defining the path correctly

Tags: python

variable 'x' is not defining the path correctly

I'm getting this error:

```
    with open(filename) as json_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Sajid\\Desktop\\cuckoo (1)\\cuckoo\\storage\\analyses\\x\\reports\\report.json'
```

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import json
import shutil    

for x in range(3,5):
    path = Path( r'C:\Users\Sajid\Desktop\cuckoo (1)\cuckoo\storage\analyses\x\reports')
    filename = os.path.join(path,"report.json")
    with open(filename) as json_file:
        data=json.load(json_file)
        var = os.path.join(str(path), os.path.basename(data['target']['file']['md5']))
        json_file.close()
        print(var)
        os.rename(filename,var)
```

I want this code to give the right path

Comment: Can you provide an example of the right path? I don't see the usage of x anywhere in the path that is being provided

Comment: I'm guessing you're not formatting the path properly. Your path string should be `'C:\Users\Sajid\Desktop\cuckoo (1)\cuckoo\storage\analyses\{0}\reports'.format(x)`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're expecting `x` to be evaluated as a variable inside a string. Python does not evaluate characters inside strings as variables unless you tell it to with the string [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method or with [format strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings).

## In Python 2.7+ and Python 3+

```
path = Path( r'C:\Users\Sajid\Desktop\cuckoo (1)\cuckoo\storage\analyses\x\reports')
```

should be

```
path = Path( r'C:\Users\Sajid\Desktop\cuckoo (1)\cuckoo\storage\analyses\{}\reports'.format(x))
```

## In Python 3.6+ (in addition to previous)

```
path = Path(r'C:\Users\Sajid\Desktop\cuckoo (1)\cuckoo\storage\analyses\x\reports')
```

should be

```
path = Path(f'C:\Users\Sajid\Desktop\cuckoo (1)\cuckoo\storage\analyses\{x}\reports')
```

Comment: If OP is using Python 3.x, they could do `f'C:\Users\Sajid\Desktop\cuckoo (1)\cuckoo\storage\analyses\{x}\reports'`. But OP didn't specify, so this is a fun fact.

Comment: I could be wrong, but is the `json_file.close()` necessary?

Comment: @HS-nebula Python 3.6, to be exact.

Comment: @HS-nebula OP has stylistic issues that are better answered at Code Review Stack Exchange. The `json_file.close()` is one of them.

Comment: Also, as this *answer* doesn't mention `json_file.close()` at all, that comment would be more appropriate on the question itself.